# tinyMCE impossible to type when in a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce

I use 2 instances of tinyMCE in my website.

Both are created properly and the get() sends me the proper id.

My first editor : #model_editor is initialised and displayed on page loaded.

My second editor: #headerfooter_editor is initialised on page loaded, but inside a div which is hidden (#settings-1).
It gets displayed on the visible container (#settings-content) when user click on a button as following :

```
$('#settings-menu-general').click (function () {
    var temp_html = $('#settings-1').html();
    $('#settings-content').html(temp_html);
});
```

In this case tinyMCE is drawn, but no interaction is possible (typing, buttons, etc....).
There should be a focus issue here but I don't get it.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem with tinymce3 and found out that it helps to have the tinymce source element made visible just right before initializing the editor (tinymce hides its source element anyway).
Otherwise i had strange editor behaviour.

So the following code is used to set the editor content?

```
$('#settings-menu-general').click (function () {
    var temp_html = $('#settings-1').html();
    $('#settings-content').html(temp_html);
});
```

Comment: nope. that's how I transfer the editor from the hidden div to the displayed div.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Thariama I have moved the initialisation of the editor to the moment it is displayed instead of the page load and it works fine. To do so I have used the callback trick for the html() method :

```
$('#settings-content').html(temp_html).promise().done(function(){
        //your callback logic / code here
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#headerfooter_editor",
            entity_encoding : "raw",
            encoding: "UTF-8",
            theme: "modern",
            height: "500px",
            width: "100%",
            variables_list : variable_array,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern modelinsert"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            toolbar2: "variable_insert | question_insert",
            image_advtab: true,
            init_instance_callback : "mceInitInstance",
            templates: [
                {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
                {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
            ]
        });
```

Comment: Didn't know promise till now. The tinymce way would be to use the tinymce editor init event and bind a handler to that one. Plus one for sharing your working solution.